# Update function when page changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension for twitter and the only issue I'm running into is that when you scroll down on twitter, it adds to the page right? Well I need my jquery function to be updated when that happens, or else the click function isn't going to work on the newly loaded tweets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need the jQuery function [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) prefreably.

Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.yourClass', function() {
    //doSomething
});
```

This will assure that the new generated content will also be affected.